# Can I set the Pi3 to automatically lock on bootup?

Tags: boot

I'd like my Raspberry Pi to immediately go to the lock screen upon boot up, similar to Windows. Every tutorial I find is for locking it after awhile though, and I can't find a single one that explains how to lock the computer on boot. How can I lock the computer on bootup?

Comment: Unless you over-ride this you have to login. See `raspi-config`

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you know what the pi user password is on your machine, because you'll now need it to login!

Next, open Terminal. Type `sudo raspi-config` and press Enter.
Use the arrows to navigate to `System Options` and press enter. Then `Boot / Auto Login`, then `Desktop GUI, requiring user to login`. Press enter then reboot.